# How to call the a bare-bones red-black tree using xtree in the STL?

Tags: c++, stl

In xtree in the STL, there is a red-black tree class (called _Tree). My goal is to make an object of this class so that I can have a minimal red-black tree. Yet, there is no default constructor. The class is only supposed to be inherited by other classes (for the use of sets and multisets and things like that).

To do this I tried creating a default constructor so that I can create an object of _Tree, but whenever I try I get tons of syntax errors. Would anyone know a way to go about doing this?

Comment: By 'STL', do you mean the standard library as provided with ISO C++, or do you mean something else? There's no `_Tree` as part of the ISO standard library.

Comment: @Tim: It's an internal implementation class, either with Dinkumware or MSVC's derivation thereof.

Comment: OK. In that case, I think it's misleading to refer to it as 'STL'.

Comment: I'm sorry guys. I thought that xtree was in the STL. I don't know what I'm doing really.

Comment: In what way is `std::set` not sufficient to your needs?

Answer (score 4):

Write your own. No, really- messing with someone else's implementation details is something you should never do. Especially since `std::set` provides this functionality already.

Comment: Writing your own RB-tree is notoriously difficult to get right, so reusing an existing implementation is not a bad idea. Better advice might be to look for a RB-tree library that's designed to be reused. The standard library implementations are generally optimised towards fulfilling the requirements of the ISO standard containers with maximum performance, not for being reusable components that are user-extensible.

Comment: So you're saying that the red-black tree in xtree is not supposed to be implemented by a user? I figured that maybe I could be able to add some code so that I could create an object of it, but I feel that this requires advanced knowledge of the xtree header file. I was hoping that maybe there was a simpler way of doing this that I'm overlooking. Thanks again for these responses, they're very helpful.

Comment: @Rob: You're completely not ever supposed to even read it, let alone actually do anything with it. Just use `std::set`- that's what it's for.

Comment: But lets say that I accidentally deleted the set header file but I need to use the red-black tree. Would there be a way to modify _Tree in xtree so that I would be able to use it?

Comment: @Rob: C'mon, just don't do it. If you delete `<set>`, reinstall your library. Just don't touch the internal stuff.

Comment: @Rob: You can probably re-download `<set>` from your compiler's website, or obtain it from whatever install medium you used, or even an automatic repair tool.

Answer (score 3):

[Re my retagging: I assumed that you're using Dinkumware STL (given that you mentioned an `xtree` header). Retag if that's not the case.]

Surely, you should be able to make a minimal subclass of `_Tree` and be done? Then you won't need to modify the `_Tree` class at all. (I don't have a copy of Dinkumware, so I can't verify that this works. But it seems a sensible thing to try.)

My answer only touches on what you *can* do. As for what you *should* do, see the other answers. :-)

Answer (score 3):

In Dinkumware STL, all headers that begin with an 'x', eg. `<xutility>`, `<xtree>`, `<xxwrap>` and so on are for ***internal use only***. Don't include it, don't use it. Simple as that. Also, everything that begins with an underscore followed by a capital letter shouldn't be used. They're the "ugly syntax" like STL calls them, and are also for ***internal use only***.